# connect windows application with database that is hosted on web

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, web

I have a webpage , that allows users to create account, login, forgot password.I also create a windows application. I want to connect this app with database that is hosted on web. how can i do this ? i need only database

Comment: Have a look at how to develop web services.

Answer (score 0):

Publish your website as a Web Service and access that web service in your windows application. 
Have a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service) to create webservices.

Comment: is any solution for only access the database?

Comment: If you are using c#, use ado.net for db connection. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307283 use your web server name in SqlConnection and provide the database you want to access. @Varsha

Comment: ok sir.. i need one more help,   I had connected  MS access to my app as per you said but I want one  local MS access database also in my application because whenever the internet connection detected, i want to copy my datas to the web server database..  How can i do this? please help me

Comment: Insted of using some local database, use datasets. which will be more handy and also you can avoid load on the database. @Varsha